# Rails 4 activeadmin - undefined local variable or method `view_factory' for :Arbre::Context

Tags: activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

i am using activeadmin gem for my admin interface,now i created a new controller and added layout 'acitveadmin'

am getting the below error

> ```
> NameError in MeetingRooms#index
>
> Showing /home/amp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-41d5176f3682/app/views/layouts/active_admin.html.arb
> ```
>
> where line #2 raised:
>
> ```
> undefined local variable or method `view_factory' for :Arbre::Context
> ```

my controller is
app/controllers/meeting_rooms_controller.rb

```
class MeetingRoomsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'active_admin'
  def index
    @meeting_rooms = MeetingRoom.all  
    #render :layout => "active_admin"
  end
end
```

can any one please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the controller block to define actions.

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/8-custom-actions.md#modifying-the-controller

```
ActiveAdmin.register MeetingRoom do

  controller do
    # This code is evaluated within the controller class

    def define_a_method
      # Instance method
    end
  end

end
```

In the controller block you can use the feature of the InheritedResources.
https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources#overwriting-actions